# Reassigning Variables when Passing Structures to Functions in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, arguments, conventions, structure

I'm working with a series of MatLab functions that take 10+ single-value arguments. I've used structures to pass the arguments to keep the code readable. An example of a function header (input is a structure):

```
function output = myFunction(input)
```

I'm finding that typing the structure name throughout the code makes it more difficult to read:

```
calc1 = input.var1 * input.var2;
calc2 = input.var2 * input.var3;
```

I realize the example above could conveniently use an array, but most of my arguments are unrelated and of varying types. Additionally, the operations I'm carrying out on the variables are more complicated than the example above and don't lend themselves to an array.

I could create variable names to accept the values from the input structure:

```
function output = myFunction(input)

var1 = input.var1;
var2 = input.var2;
var3 = input.var3;

calc1 = var1 * var2;
calc2 = var2 * var3;
```

Doing this creates a long block at the top of the function which does nothing but reassign the input variables, and the data has to be copied so there is a performance penalty. On the other hand, the code is easier to read.

Is there any coding convention that could provide guidance? I've found plenty of resources here and on Google that suggest passing large amounts of data to MatLab functions using structures, but precious little on how to do so intelligently.

Comment: I don't know your code but I don't think typing the structure name makes it difficult to read. On the contrary I think it makes it very clear that you are using an input variable in the calculation. If it really bothers you, you could choose a shorter name like `in` which is still clear but produces less clutter.

Comment: I agree with @denahiro - you should not assign 'simple' variables; just rename the input argument if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I've changed the input structure name to 'in' and left out the new variable names. I also changed the function output to a structure named 'out'. I've found that makes it easier to spot certain bugs. If I see in.<anything> on the left side of an assignment expression, I know something is amiss!

Answer (score 1):

How about if you write a function that parses the input arguments, and design it so that it accepts either a structure as input, or a list of variables.

Example:

```
function output = myFunc(varargin)
    narginchk(1,3);
    [var1,var2,var3] = parseInput(varargin{:});

    fprintf('var 1 = %g\n', var1);
    fprintf('var 2 = %g\n', var2);
    fprintf('var 3 = %g\n', var3);
    output = var1+var2+var3;
end

function [var1,var2,var3] = parseInput(varargin)
    if nargin == 1 && isstruct(varargin{1})
        var1 = varargin{1}.var1;
        var2 = varargin{1}.var2;
        var3 = varargin{1}.var3;
    elseif nargin == 3
        [var1,var2,var3] = deal(varargin{:});
    else
        error('myFunc:parseInput', 'Incorrect input')
    end
end
```

Now we can call the function as:

```
x = myFunc(1,2,3)
```

or:

```
in = struct('var1',1, 'var2',2, 'var3',3);
x = myFunc(in)
```

Of course you could add more strict validation to check the input (see  `validateattributes` and `InputParser`)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I need to make this code as understandable as possible to non-professional programmers (much like me for that matter). I don't think adding this extra code will make things any clearer. I'll keep it in mind for future projects where I can afford to be a bit more technical.